# Reading BCP files in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, bcp

Is there any Java library (or example code) for reading files produced by the command-line Microsoft [Bulk Copy (BCP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) utility, used for importing/exporting SQL Server data?

Some similar work is done on [Free TDS](http://www.freetds.org/) and [jbcp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbcp/), but I am mainly interested in reading raw BCP files (ASCII or binary) and processing their contents, not inserting data into SQL Server.

So, a **pure Java "BCP reader"** utility would be ideal.

Also, is there a good **online reference for the BCP format** (including format patterns and example data)?

If an **open source parser for BCP files** exists, even not in Java, that would help as well.

Comment: Anyone with any information on this?